# Websphere 8.5 Upgrade issue with while translating page

Tags: websphere, websphere-8

**Error Message:**
We are upgrading websphere from 6.1 to 8.5 and hitting following error
JSPG0228E: Exception caught while translating /WEB-INF/jsp/oasp/mhist.jsp: error in statically included file /WEB-INF/jsp/oasp/mcheck.jsp(126,8) --> JSPG0122E: Unable to parse EL function ${fn:contains(sp.class.name, 'mappotential')}.

**Root Cause:**

com.ibm.ws.jsp.translator.JspTranslationException: JSPG0228E: Exception caught while translating /WEB-INF/jsp/oasp/mhist.jsp: error in statically included file /WEB-INF/jsp/oasp/mcheck.jsp(126,8) --> JSPG0122E: Unable to parse EL function ${fn:contains(sp.class.name, 'mappotential')}.
at com.ibm.ws.jsp.translator.visitor.validator.ELValidator.validateElFunction(ELValidator.java:505) at com.ibm.ws.jsp.translator.visitor.validator.ELValidator.validateELExpression(ELValidator.java:123)   at com.ibm.ws.jsp.translator.visitor.validator.ELValidator.validateELExpression(ELValidator.java:150)   at com.ibm.ws.jsp.translator.visitor.validator.ValidateVisitor.validateCustomTagAttribute(ValidateVisitor.java:1752)    at com.ibm.ws.jsp.translator.visitor.validator.ValidateVisitor.validateCustomTagAttributeValues(ValidateVisitor.java:1400)  at com.ibm.ws.jsp.translator.visitor.validator.ValidateVisitor.visitCustomTagStart(ValidateVisitor.java:294)

Comment: hi, it might be this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17744158/jspg0122e-unable-to-parse-el-function-in-websphere-8

Comment: Have you tried scanning the app using the binary application migration toolkit IBM provides? https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/node/6250913

I know there is a rule that will flag reserved words being used like in IronMan's comment.